# React Native: Iterate through array of strings and render content based on element

Tags: react-native

React Native and JavaScript noob here. Currently, I have a JavaScript array such as

```
var my_stuff = ['text', 'img src=some_img.jpg', 'moretext']
```

I am able to render the contents of the array by simply using

```
 render(){
     {my_stuff}
 }
```

And I will see on my app:

```
 text
 img src=some_img.jpg
 moretext
```

But how would I be able to render the image, since it is currently hardcoded. Is there a way for me to iterate through my array and render each element one at a time, but check beforehand if it contains 'img src=' at the start and render that as a react native image instead?

Is there a better approach to what I'm trying to accomplish if this is not the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few components to your question. First, the way you are rendering your data needs to be a bit more structured. Considering your same hardcoded array

```
var my_stuff = ['text', 'some_img.jpg', 'moretext']
```

A hardcoded way of rendering this correctly would be

```
 render(){
   <Text>{my_stuff[0]}</Text>
   <Image source={require(my_stuff[1])}/>
   <Text>{my_stuff[1]}</Text>
 }
```

It then becomes clear that your data needs to be structured as well. You need a way to identify if each object in your array is a *Text* or an *Image*. Something like

```
var my_stuff = [{text: 'text'}, {image: 'some_img.jpg'}, {text: 'moretext'}]
```

Then from there it's much easier to know what type of item you should be rendering. You can then iterate through the array and return one render item per array item.